# How do I run Vagrant as a normal user in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, vagrant, libvirt

I am trying to setup Vagrant in Fedora 23 with `libvirt`. It boots and everything looks fine until I get asked for "sudo password: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required".

I run Vagrant as a normal user and do not want to run it as root, nor add myself to the sudoers file. Just to test, I have run `vagrant up` as root and everything worked, but I am not comfortable with running Vagrant like this.

I found something while googling for fixes and that was to change the permissions of the `/etc/exports` file. This works and let me run `vagrant up` as a normal user, but it feels like a dirty fix to me. What is the downside with changing the permissions of the /etc/exports file? I would really like to get Vagrant running as a normal user without having to affect security.

Virtualbox is not an alternative due to the kernel updates. I do not want to risk anything breaking or wait for Oracle or rpmfusion updating the kernel modules for Virtualbox.

**I have followed these instructions from Fedora Developer portal:**

```
$ sudo dnf install vagrant-libvirt
$ sudo systemctl enable libvirtd
$ lsmod | grep kvm
```

lsmod | grep kvm does not return anything, so I have edit the Vagrantfile to use the qemu driver:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
...
  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
    libvirt.driver = "qemu"
  end
...
end
```

**Using libvirt from Vagrant without password prompts**

```
$ sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} libvirt
$ newgrp libvirt
Synced folders with NFS

$ sudo dnf install nfs-utils && sudo systemctl enable nfs-server
```

**Afterwards enable nfs, rpc-bind and mountd services for firewalld:**

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=nfs &&
  sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=rpc-bind &&
  sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=mountd &&
  sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

**Using NFS shares from Vagrant without password prompts**

```
$ sudo visudo
```

add this:

```
# Allow Vagrant to manage /etc/exports
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD = /usr/bin/tee -a /etc/exports
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_CHECK = /usr/bin/systemctl status nfs-server.service
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_START = /usr/bin/systemctl start nfs-server.service
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_APPLY = /usr/sbin/exportfs -ar
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE = /bin/sed -r -e * d -ibak /etc/exports
%vagrant ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD, VAGRANT_NFSD_CHECK, VAGRANT_NFSD_START, VAGRANT_NFSD_APPLY, VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE
```

**Afterwards add yourself to the vagrant group if you are not there already by running:**

```
$ sudo getent group vagrant >/dev/null || sudo groupadd -r vagrant
$ sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} vagrant
$ newgrp vagrant
```

**Get Vagrant up and running:**

```
$ vagrant init rboyer/ubuntu-trusty64-libvirt 
$ vagrant up
```

**I have tried two different libvirt boxes from Vagrant box site:** [here](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/s3than/boxes/trusty64) and [here](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/rboyer/boxes/ubuntu-trusty64-libvirt)

Help on this matter is very appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Do you need [synced folders](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/) in the first place?

Comment: It's not trying to run your VM or even Vagrant as Root, it's simply trying to edit `/etc/exports` so as to implemented a synced directory between the host and the VM.  Do to this, you need root privileges to make the change.  You will get the same prompt for `vagrant destroy` when you are done, to remove the selfsame edits to `/etc/exports`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry upfront for being somewhat noob (are starting on a computer degree this fall and are trying to learn as much as possible). I understand that I need to give root privileges to make the change, but when I run as a normal user and get this prompt, my password do not work since I am not in the sudoers file and I can't change to root in the boot process. I tought the section "Using NFS shares from Vagrant without password prompts" was supposed to take care of this. Do I have to use vagrant up from root or can I fix this so that I can run vagrant up as a normal user?